# Does chromium-browser use the GPU?

Tags: web-browsers

I am trying to figure out the correct CPU/GPU split for the main use case of browsing the web.  Chrome dosen't appear to be able to play video at the moment.

Does Chrome use the GPU at all?  Would it be ok to set the GPU to 16 and CPU to 496?

Answer (score 1):

Type "chrome:flags" into your address bar and look for graphics/GPU/3d/acceleration options. Then check "chrome:gpu" to see if it uses Hardware acceleration.

I don't think setting GPU memory to 16 will improve performance since at least the OS uses the GPU (unless you are using VNC or something similar) but if you try it, post results or add it to the wiki.

Comment: I don't think Chrome supports hard float.

Comment: @Jivings Don't floating point operations run on the CPU?